# std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false), advantages, disadvantages?

Tags: c++, io, iostream, cstdio

What is the difference between `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio( false );`
Vs `std::cout.sync_with_stdio( false );` and `std::cin.sync_with_stdio( false );`?

Which one should I use supposing my code does not use any of the C streams from `<cstdio>` and only uses C++ streams from `<iostream>`?

I want to know:

1. what are the advantages of disabling the synchronization?
2. What can go wrong if synchronization is set to **false**? Which things should I take into account if I want to disable the synchronization?

Comment: One question by question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sync_with_stdio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) is a `static` function.

so

```
std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);
```

is in fact

```
std::cout, std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Comment: I don't understand the last line though.

Comment: `std::cout` is evaluated (and result discarded). It is basically equivalent to `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);`.

Comment: So no difference? I thought `std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);` only disables the synchronization for std::cout and `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` disables synchronization for all the eight C++ stream objects. Isn't this true?

Comment: @digito_evo If you don't understand the expression containing a comma then you probably should read about the [built-in comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) in C++.

Comment: @heap underrun Thanks for the link. Now I understand it.