# Fast I/O question for competitive programming what does the arrow operator (->) do in this case?

Tags: c++, io, cin, cout

What is the difference between

```
cin.tie(0);
ios:sync_with_stdio(0);
```

and

```
cin.tie(0) -> sync_with_stdio(0);
```

I do this so that both cin and cout become faster and I use the cin.tie(0) to reduce the runtime when I am interleaving cin and cout. I just want to know what the difference is between the two because I can't find an answer anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither of them is C and C++. Why have you tagged it with these languages?

Comment: what are you talking about? This is c/c++??? https://usaco.guide/general/fast-io?lang=cpp

Comment: I can't compile either of these snippets, there are missing a number of code lines to make these valid.

Comment: Relevant background reading: [Significance of ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31162367/11082165)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::ios\_base::sync\_with\_stdio(false), advantages, disadvantages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70302865/stdios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-advantages-disadvantages). As explained there, `sync_with_stdio` is a static member function, so it doesn't matter which instance of `ios_base` you call it on (or whether you call it on an instance at all). Whoever wrote the second snippet either doesn't know what `sync_with_stdio` is, or they intentionally obfuscated their code for a "coolness" factor

Comment: @Brian More likely they just want to save a few key strokes, since the goal here is to write the program as quickly as possible. Of course using such code as reference is a terrible way to learn the language.

Comment: @gnarayan The code is definitively not C at all. And in C++ `:` doesn't make sense there. You probably mean `::`.

Comment: It is not a good idea to learn the language from competitive programming code. Learn the language properly first, e.g. from one of the [recommended books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and then lookup references to the functions you are using, e.g. on https://cppreference.com. Then it would be clear to you what happens here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean `::` instead of `:` and that you are using `using namespace std;` (which is generally considered bad style because it can lead to problems, see [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)), then there is no difference between the two snippets.

As you can see in a reference for the function [`std::basic_ios::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie), the overload you are using returns a pointer to the previously tied stream as `std::basic_ostream*`.

In the reference for the function [`std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) you can see that it is a static member function of `std::ios_base`. So we can call it on any instance of `std::ios_base`. [`std::basic_ostream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) inherits from `std::ios_base` as also shown in the reference, so we can also call it on the `std::basic_ostream*` pointer returned from `cin.tie(0)`.

`->` is just the indirect member access as usual, used here to perform the member function call on the pointer returned by `cin.tie(0)`.